# Design being messed-up after deploying on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, azure, azure-web-app-service

My application looks fine when I run on the localhost via visual studio but it creates mess when I publish it on the AZURE Web App Service. I am using free tier of Azure web app service.

[Image of the header of homepage at the local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Cdl.jpg)

[Image of the header of homepage at the Azure web app-service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb5oT.png)

[Home page items at the localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe8ds.png)

[Home page items at azure web-app-service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufYdn.png)

[Button at the homepage at localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5VBR.png)

[Button at azure web-app-service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTASY.png)

My link to the site is https://auctionit.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the console tab, you'll see that some files were not properly loaded. I believe this is why the layout is broken, no problems on Azure side.

[image]

Comment: what to do then with these files?

Comment: it the error from your website. I have no clues what they mean. Open the developer toolbar and you'll see

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with the Azure free tier.

From what you have shown here, this is something to do with the styles. Check your css and inline styles. Make sure all the css and other style related resources are deployed correctly.